# Building NodeMCU firmware

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to build nodemcu firmware by cloning the github and using the make command, https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware.  I'm using a raspberry pi, which could the issue.  I am not modifying anything, just cloning the master branch and typing make.  Wondering if I am missing a prerequisite.  Below is what I get with V=1 make

> make: Entering directory '/home/pi/Documents/nodemcu-firmware' PRUNE
>   libmain.a libc.a
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/Documents/nodemcu-firmware/tools/toolchains/esp8266-linux-x86_64-20181106.0/bin
>   /home/pi/Documents/nodemcu-firmware/tools/toolchains/esp8266-linux-x86_64-20181106.0/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/Documents/nodemcu-firmware/tools/toolchains/esp8266-linux-x86_64-20181106.0/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected Makefile:331: recipe for target
>   '/home/pi/Documents/nodemcu-firmware/sdk/.pruned-3.0-e4434aa' failed
>   make: ***
>   [/home/pi/Documents/nodemcu-firmware/sdk/.pruned-3.0-e4434aa] Error 2
>   make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Documents/nodemcu-firmware'

Comment: What is the purpose of building on RPi?

Comment: RPi works well for working with ESP-01, 3.3V rail and serial pins...I have been using the download firmware and wanted to try using the direct build.  Thanks all!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/docs/build.md),

> Linux Build Environment
>
> The NodeMCU project embeds a ready-made tool chain for Linux/x86-64 by default.

Which means that you can build it only on Linux running on x86-64 architecture. Since RPi is ARM-based, you cannot build this project on it.

Comment: That's correct but we've also got a Docker image for building. And that, at least in theory, can also run on a RPi.

Comment: .../esp8266-linux-x86_64-20181106.0/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar - that look suspiciously like an x86_64 binary being interpreted as a script.

Comment: Wouldn’t docker also have issues with ARM architecture?

Comment: I tried docker on the RPi and couldn't get it to work.  My solution was an Ubuntu OS running on a USB drive...